# How can TO ovrride css custom class above by bootstrap btn class?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have `CSS` file in my project, and this global `CSS` class:

```
input[Type=text], input[Type=password], input[Type=button], input[Type=submit]
{
    margin: .2em .05em;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #333333;
}
```

In `CSS` this I  imported bootstrap.

```
@import url('../bootstrap.min.css');
```

My question is how can I ovrride css class above by bootstrap btn class?

Comment: What do you mean by `how can I ovrride css class above by bootstrap btn class?`..Can please explain

Comment: @neophyte I want to override existing CSS by bootstrap.

Comment: Just add your custom css file after bootstrap css file in your page..that's it.

Comment: Can you post example?

Comment: added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the submit button if you don't add the custom css after the bootstrap css you will get white text color inside button . But your custom css is overriding it hence you get red.

**with custom css**

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
input[Type=text], input[Type=password], input[Type=button], input[Type=submit]
{
    margin: .2em .05em;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: red;
    
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text">
<input Type="password">
<input Type="button">
<input class="btn btn-info" Type="submit">
```

**Without custom css**

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text">
<input Type="password">
<input Type="button">
<input class="btn btn-info" Type="submit">
```

Comment: Thanks for post.Do I need add class "btn"  to HTML element  to make bootstrap appereance . Or I can some how inherit the it in css custom class?

Comment: Yes you need to add that to get the above mentioned appearence..otherwise you can't have that look and also you need to do a lot of css..we use bootstrap to avoid that much work. just use custom css to change the colors and add a custom margin this sort of small adjustments.

Comment: I added.But I dont want to add "btn btn-info" classes to each element.Can I get bootstrap appereance without adding  "btn btn-info" classes to each element?

Comment: then check the css for .btn and .btn-info class from console of your browser..copy it and paste it inside you custom css.. `input[Type=button]{ HERE }`

Comment: Can custom css class inherit from bootstrap class?

Comment: I think you should use http://lesscss.org/ less..checkout...also check this it states how to compile custom css using bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0):

You can override existing CSS directives one of two ways.

You can either provide a more explicit selection than other selections, by selecting the element by `id`, or you can follow the attribute with the `!important` flag, such as:

```
input[Type=text], input[Type=password], input[Type=button], input[Type=submit]
{
    margin: .2em .05em;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #333333 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html file put your CSS file after @import like this

```
<head>
@import url('../bootstrap.min.css');
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

but you can also use !important as Mike said. You can of course also change the button styling in the bootstrap CSS file but I don't recommend doing that.